# Module 'Tensorflow' has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: tensorflow, summary

I am executing a program containing the following lines:

```
def write_log(callback, name, loss, batch_no):
    """
    Write training summary to TensorBoard
    """
    summary = tf.Summary()
    summary_value = summary.value.add()
    summary_value.simple_value = loss
    summary_value.tag = name
    callback.writer.add_summary(summary, batch_no)
    callback.writer.flush()
```

`summary = tf.Summary()` is causing the following error

> Error:  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Summary'

Tensorflow version I am using is 2.3.0. Remaining functions related to 'TensorFlow' are working fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide information such as the error message and the version of TensorFlow you are using?

Comment: Yeah Updated @Panther314

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary) of tensorflow, the usage of the tensorboard summary is different now:

```py
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer("/tmp/mylogs")
with writer.as_default():
  for step in range(100):
    # other model code would go here
    tf.summary.scalar("my_metric", 0.5, step=step)
    writer.flush()
```